# Tkinter and Python Login System

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a LOGIN SYSTEM using Python and I'm also using Tkinter as a GUI...

I have written some code but I'm not able to figure out exactly how to frame a loop for incorrect credentials...
Need help in correcting the code and making a full proof login system

**P.S: I also wanna add more credentials!**

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def validateLogin(username, password):
   print("username entered :", username.get())
   print("password entered :", password.get())
   return

#window
tkWindow = Tk()  
tkWindow.geometry('400x150')  
tkWindow.title('Tkinter Login Form - pythonexamples.org')

#username label and text entry box
usernameLabel = Label(tkWindow, text="User Name").grid(row=0, column=0)
username = StringVar()
usernameEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=username).grid(row=0, column=1)  

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)  
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)  

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, username, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=0)  

tkWindow.mainloop()

if (username == alexa) :
        if (password == 123):
                print("Welcome!!")
         
        else :
                print("Sorry Try Again")
                if (username == alexa) :
                        if (password == 123):
                                print("Welcome!!")
                            
                else :
                        print("Sorry Try Again")
```

Comment: Code after `mainloop()` will only get executed, after the code is closed.

Comment: The validation logic code should be put inside `validateLogin()` function.  Also `validateLogin()` should not take any arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using if else is going to make your code lengthy specifically when you need to validate more credentials. Use a dictionary to save the credentials and then compare the user text with the credentials.

Here is an example code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def validateLogin():

     user_entry = [entry.get() for entry in entryLst]
     correct = 0
     
     for x in zip(*credentials.values()):

        if list(x) == user_entry:
            print("credentials matched")
            correct=1
            break

     if correct == 0:
         print("Incorrect credentials")

#window
tkWindow = Tk()  
tkWindow.geometry('400x150')  
tkWindow.title('Tkinter Login Form - pythonexamples.org')

credentials = {'User Name': ['alexa', 'random'], 'Password': ['123', '1234'], 'Email': ['alexa@mail.com', 'random@mail.com']}

entryLst = []

for index, cred in enumerate(credentials.keys()):
    Label(tkWindow, text=cred).grid(row=index, column=0)
    
    ent = Entry(tkWindow)
    ent.grid(row=index, column=1)
    entryLst.append(ent)


#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=0)  

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add and remove accounts without updating the app constantly, I would suggest not hardcoding the accounts into your application, but rather into a webhost (a free suggestion is Pastebin)

## Without a webhost

```
accounts = {"user1": "password1", "user2", "password2"}

def validateLogin(username, password):
   print("username entered :", username.get())
   print("password entered :", password.get())
   
   user = username.get()
   pword = password.get()

   if accounts[user] == pword: # Check if password matches username in the dictionary 'accounts'.
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

## With a webhost

This is what the webhost should look like:

```
user1::password1
user2::password2
```

```
import requests

accounts = requests.get("YOUR WEBHOST URL").split("\n")

def validateLogin(username, password):
   print("username entered :", username.get())
   print("password entered :", password.get())
   
   user = username.get()
   pword = password.get()

   if f"{user}::{pword}" in accounts:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```